# Why do I keep getting this ndarray callable error, and what does it mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

With my code below, I keep getting the error

> 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

but I'm not sure what this means or where it is occurring.

```
##LAGRANGE POLYNOMIAL:
import pylab
%pylab inline
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy

def y(x):
    return x**3

def plot_approx(f,xi):
    x=numpy.linspace(0.5, 3.5, 13)
    plot(x, f(x))
    lagrange_polynomial=scipy.interpolate,lagrange(xi,f(xi))
    plot(x, lagrange_polynomial(x))
    show()

x = numpy.array([1., 2., 3.,]) #given in question

plot_approx(y(x), numpy.array([1., 2., 3.,]))
```

Comment: When reporting an error, you should indicate which line in your code is producing that.  In this case `Mitch` made a reasonable guess (the `f(x)` expression), but often it isn't easy to tell by just reading code.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the result of `y(x)` to `plot_approx`, where it expects a function object as opposed to as a returned array from the function. Consequently, the error is telling you that an array is not callable when attempting to call `f(x)` where `f` is your array.

You should instead call `plot_approx` with the actual function object `y`,

```
plot_approx(y, numpy.array([1., 2., 3.,]))
```